Why are cores 1 and 3 stuck in offline mode in Linux?
I have a system running with a CPU that has the following info from lscpu:
CPU(s):                   4
  On-line CPU(s) list:    0,2
  Off-line CPU(s) list:   1,3
Vendor ID:                GenuineIntel
  Model name:             Doesn't matter
    CPU family:           6
    Model:                42
    Thread(s) per core:   1
    Core(s) per socket:   2
    Socket(s):            1

Now I can't seem to get CPUs 1 and 3 to come online. I have tried setting the value of /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/online but get a permissions error whenever I try (using sudo).
Is this a case of the CPU has 2 cores and hyper-threading? If so does this need to be enabled via the BIOS? If it's not a hyper-threading thing, any idea why I cant get these cores online?

Cores aside, how are you trying to use sudo? I'm 70% certain the permission errors come from sudo misuse and the command is not actually getting to the point of trying to change anything.

@grawity_u1686 I'm running the following: sudo echo 1 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/online. I've also tried sudo nano /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/online but cannot save the file after making edits.

@shortspider With sudo echo 1 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/online the redirection is performed by your shell which doesn't have sudo permission. Try echo 1 | tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/online instead. If that doesn't work, what does ls -l /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/online show?

@ChesterGillon I tried what you suggested, also tried with sudo before the tee and got tee: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/online: Operation not permitted.
The ls command gives -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jun  9 09:46 /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/online

@shortspider Oops, my previous suggestion was incorrect I should have said echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/online but you tried sudo before the tee and got Operation not permitted, rather than Operation not permitted. Based upon that, the answer might help. That stackoverflow answer suggests the issue is Simultaneous Multithreading (SMT), also known as Hyper-Threading (HT).

@ChesterGillon that worked like a charm, thank you!

Debugging steps in the comments on the question found that attempting to write to 1 to /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/online with sudo permission failed with Operation not permitted.
Based upon that, the stack overflow answer to echo 1 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/online Write error suggests the issue is that Simultaneous Multithreading (SMT) in turned off, which is also known as Hyper-Threading (HT). The referenced thread has instructions on how to turn on SMT in Linux, and then turn on the processors.
For the system in the question to turn on SMT:
echo on | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/smt/control

And then to turn on the processors:
echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/online
echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/online

Depending upon the PC, could also potentially enable SMT in the BIOS (which is probably named Hyper Threading).
